# Creating a "flashlight" with JavaScript and HTML. Having trouble switching between colors

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to HTML and JavaScript so be friendly. I need to create a "flashlight" that changes from black to white and visa versa on click. I can make it to where I can click the screen and it will switch to white but how can I switch it back to black? Should I use an if statement?

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function body_load() {
}

function on_click() {
document.getElementById("divMain").style.background = "#FFFFFF";
}
```

and the HTML:

```
body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background-color:#FF0000;
overflow:auto;
}

#divMain {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:320px;
height:460px;
background-color:black;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}

</style>

</head>

<body 
onload="body_load();" 
onclick="on_click();"
>

<div 
id="divMain">
</div>
```

I can only change code in the JavaScript file however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other answer, but if you only need black and white, you can use this as well:

```
function on_click() {
    var div = document.getElementById("divMain");

    if (div.style.background === "white") {
        div.style.background = "black";
    } else {
        div.style.background = "white";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a conditional if statement to determine if the background needs to change, here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fhPgZ/)

```
function on_click() {
    var div = document.getElementById("divMain");
    if (div.style.background != 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
        div.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
    else
        div.style.background = "#000000";
}
```

Comment: @AlienArrays - That is excessive and is not mentioned by the OP. If you feel the need to add requirements of that type of nature, then it would be best if you posted your own answer.

Comment: That works however I need it to change back to black when I click it again.